# ReactJS display fetch response onClick

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Im working on a ReactJS project where you can generate a random activity when pressing the generate button. Im doing a fetch to my api to display some data from it. This works fine. Now I want to do the fetch and display the returned data every time I click the generate button (which is in the home component). So the generate button has to do a new fetch and refresh the component. Also it has to be empty on default. I searched a while and can't find a relevant answer. Can some of you guys help me out? Thanks.

**fetch component**

```
import React from "react";

export class ItemLister extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { suggestion: "" };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("......./suggestions/random", {
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            }
        })
            .then(resp => {
                return resp.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ suggestion: data.suggestion });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error, "catch the hoop");
            });
    }

    render() {
        return <h2>{this.state.suggestion}</h2>;
    }
}
```

**home component**

```
import React from "react";
import { ItemLister } from "./apiCall";

export class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log();
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("name", this.props.params.name);
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", this.props.params.token);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contentContainer AD">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <p>Het is heel leuk als het werkt!</p>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <ItemLister />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div className="container center">
                    <button>GENERATE</button>
                    <button>SAVE</button>
                    <button>MATCH</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you still facing any issues with rendering suggestion?

Comment: No not with rendering. The main issue is setting an onClick in the generate button to connect the fetch function.

Comment: You want to refresh ItemListener component every time by clicking generate button. Correct?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say that you move your fetch logic to `home` component and maintain a state in `home` component just like you are doing in `Itemlister` component. Then all you have to do is pass your state to `Itemlister` component. Your home component will look like this

```
export class Home extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {suggestion: ""}
    ...
}

componentDidMount(){
  // For initial data
  this.fetchData();
}

fetchData = () => {
  fetch("......./suggestions/random", {
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    }
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
  }) 
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({ suggestion: data.suggestion })                    
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
  })
}

render() {
    return (
        ...
                <tbody >
                   // Pass state to itemlister like this
                    <tr><td><ItemLister suggestion={this.state.suggestion}/></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div className="container center">
                // Add event handler here. On every click it will fetch new data
                <button onClick={this.fetchData}>GENERATE</button>
                <button>SAVE</button>
                <button>MATCH</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And your `ItemLister` component has the responsibility to display the data via props.

```
export class ItemLister extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }

    render() {
    return(
      <h2> 
        {this.props.suggestion}
      </h2>
      )
     }
    }
```

As per the suggestion by [dubes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695393/dubes) in comment, If you don't want to maintain any state in this component then you can make this functional component like this

```
function ItemLister(props) {
  return <h2> 
            {props.suggestion}
          </h2>;
}
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner approach (and recommended one as well as per my understanding). One suggestion: the `ItemListener` component can be a [functional component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components)

Comment: This works great however, it isn't empty on default. It does a fetch when the page loads so there's already data before the user pressed generate.

Comment: @StevenvanEck If you want it empty by default then just remove `this.fetchData();` line from `componentDidMount` function.

Comment: But, fetching the data before being asked for, wouldn't risk to fetch potentially too much data and risk perfomance and memory consumption?

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure if I understood you correctly... but since you're adding your fetch inside a react extended class, you can render it inside the home component like so:

```
  state = {
    visible: false
  }

  generateItem() {
    if (this.state.visible) {
      return <ItemLister />
    }
    return <h2>nothing to show</h2>
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({visible: true})}>Click</button>
        {this.generate()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

The onClick function will update the state every time the user clicks on it and a new rerender will occur thus calling generateItem again with a new random word.

Hope this is what you were searching for.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me a lot however I need to do the fetch every time the button is clicked. Now it will only fetch the first time clicked.

Comment: It should call the fetch again once you click on the button again